# How to change this magamenu logo image?

Tags: magento2, template, menu, logo, megamenu

So, I've been trying my best to remove this menu from my magento2 megamenu but I am unable to do so. Can't change the logo image either. This thing started to suck now. Can you help me with it? The theme I am using is Claue for magento2. Thanks[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. `Content > Configuration > Select your current theme > Header > logo Image`.
2. **Clean the cache**, if it doesn't work, take a look at your admin **theme**, maybe you have some custom logo config for that and don't forget to `clean cache`, `deploy static content` for each step.

To **clean the cache** : `php bin/magento cache:clean`.

To **deploy the static content** : `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`